# How to make water droplets in My collection appear on a object on normals

Tags: particles

So I have made water droplets and they're all facing Z direction Now I'm trying to make it appear on a object but it's never rotated on the face of object on its Normal, I don't care if It's with help of Geometry node or Particle system I just want it there

[image: With Emitter]

[image: with Hair]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose these settings here:

[image]

And select your render object, TAB (edit mode), R X -90.

result:

[image]

In geometry nodes you can do this:

[image]

Comment: I've attached the file

Comment: NVM i found the error which was while i rotated them I totally forgot about the origins and once I fixed them then they started Working